# Why does my Javascript loop only return the first value?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jsx

I'm creating a loop in ES6 which will be used to loop through and output a sequence of 51 images. I've created a for loop, however it only returns the first image, image_0000.jpg, when it runs.

How come it's not returning all 51 images?

```
sequenceImages() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 51; i++) {
      return <img src={require(`../images/image_000${i}.jpg`)} alt="" />

    }
  }
```

Comment: Because you `return` inside `for`. create an array, push to it inside the loop, then return the array

Comment: or use `Array.prototype.map`

Comment: Hi,
As soon as you use return statement, it will come out of the loop. So currently, your loop is running only once. Therefore, first safe your images in an array inside the loop and outside the loop return that array.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return  . "The return statement ends function execution" <= it ends function execution, not block execution, *function* execution.

Comment: Solved, me being stupid. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your return statement exits the function immediately during the first time through the loop. It sounds like you want it to return many `<img>` tags so you can do something like this:

```
gitImage(i) {
  return <img src={require(`../images/image_000${i}.jpg`)} alt="" />
}
sequenceImages() {
  const images = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 51; i++) {
    images.push(getImage(i));
  }
  return images;
}
```